# What causes liquid helium to climb walls?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superfluidity

It is a phenomenon which can be observed if your search on the web. Apparently liquid Helium can crawl up through walls. Does every superfluid do this crawling action or is it just special for liquid helium? How is the motion of liquid Helium described and modeled in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108517/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When helium, which turns liquid at about 4.2 Kelvin, is cooled further to below approximately 2 Kelvin, it undergoes a phase change. This phase of helium, referred to as Helium II, is a superfluid. What this means is that the liquid's viscosity becomes nearly zero. At the same time, its thermal conductivity becomes infinite.

Because the viscosity is almost zero, the fluid flows very easily as a result of the smallest pressure or change in temperature. The response is so strong that even the smallest forces will help the light-weight liquid climb against the force of gravity.

If you have liquid helium inside and outside your system, the liquid inside will flow till it matches the level of the liquid outside and the temperature

Comment: Prabhdeep, have you ever investigated about the magnetic dipole moments of the molecules of Helium? Would it be possible that the magnetic dipole moments of the Helium is predominant because the thermic enregy and by this the chaotic movement of Helium is reduced to minimum?

Comment: You should [cite your sources](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1998-02/888462465.Ph.r.html)