# Superfludity and Superconductivity

Tags: electrical-resistance, superconductivity, viscosity, superfluidity

Hello Im a physics enthusiast, right now im learning about  superfluidity. My question is [superfluidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluidity) and [superconductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity) are the same thing or do they work together?

Comment: Superconductivity usually refers to *electrical conductivity*. Liquid helium cooled sufficient to be a superfluid happens to be a great *thermal conductor*. 
  Is that where the sticking-point is?

Comment: Awesome thanks. Yes this is exactly where i'm stuck at. So basically Liquid Helium can act as a super conducter at  certain temperatures?

Answer (score 0):

No, generally speaking superconductivity and superfluidity are two distinct phenomena. However, there are massive similarities between the two. E.g., in a superfluid, the fluid flows with no viscosity (no energy dissipation), whilst in a superconductor the electrons move with no resistivity (no degradation in their velocity).

These similarities lead us to treat the two systems almost like the same thing. In fact, for a while people used to call superconductivity "charged superfluidity"! But don't forget that even though there are some connections, these are typically two different phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

The superconductivity (SC) and superfluidity (SF) both have one universal origin — the Bose-Einstein-Condensation (BEC) of bosons, because BEC-bosons have a minimum and quantized kinetic energy and, thus, cannot transfer their energy to other particles by arbitrarily small portions. In case of SC a boson is an electron pair, in case of SF a boson is a neutral atom (usually — helium atom). The BEC temperature inversely depends on boson mass ($1/m$), so the critical temperature (Tc) of SC may be much higher than Tc of SF.

Comment: Welcome! We noticed that you believe this answer is also appropriate for [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76578/44126). When that happens, please flag one of the questions as a duplicate, rather than posting the identical answers in more than one place.